# Find by ObjectID using mongoose always returns null

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to search a document with _id property which is of ObjectId type. But it keeps returning null even though a document with exact _id exists.

```
const employee = require("../Models/employee");

router.get('/employees/:id', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params.id);
    employee.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, emp){
        if(err) {
            res.send("Error! " + err);
        } else {
            res.json(emp);
        }
    })
});
```

employee model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const empSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    Name: String,
    DOB: String,
    Sex: String,
    Experience: Number,
    Expertise: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('employee', empSchema, 'EmpDetails');
```

MongoDB has the _id:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59eebab187179c880ed9473b"), 
    "Name" : "Abhisek", 
    "DOB" : "04/28/1991", 
    "Sex" : "Male", 
    "Experience" : 4.0, 
    "Expertise" : "Javascript"
}
```

Console also displays the same

```
59eebab187179c880ed9473b
```

Comment: Show the document you think should match and `console.log(req.params.id)` and show what that value is. If you get nothing then they simply are not the same. Also mongoose "autocasts" so `.find({ _id: req.params.id })` is perfectly fine. So is `.findById(req.params.id)` for that matter, since it is only **one** result by the primary key.

Comment: What is the name of the collection? Is is `"employee"` or is is `"employees"`? Are you connected to the correct database? Can you actually show the logged value of `req.params.id` like you were asked to? Can you actually do `.findById(req.params.id)` like you were asked to? Can you politely acknowledge those who ask you questions?

Comment: Yes I am connected to correct database as  `employee.find()` works perfectly fine. `Console.log(req.params.id)` displays the correct value `59eebab187179c880ed9473b `. Tried with `.findById(req.params.id)` as well, but still returns null.

Comment: Mongoose is expecting the collection to be named `"employees"`. See the duplicate for how to address this.

Comment: I have  tried changing to  `"employees"` as well. But still returns null.

Comment: Dude. You have `_id: String`. Remove that. The type is automatically assigned to `ObjectId` and does not require you to specify it in the schema.